# How to play the YOUTUBE video automatically when a page loads using PHP

Tags: php, youtube

Is there any possible way to PLAY a you tube video on page load and to get the TOTAL PLAY TIME of that particular video. Any related reply will be helpful...

Thanks in advance...

Fero

Comment: I would really hate it when a video starts to play on page load. I want to decide myself when the video starts.

Comment: PHP is not involved in playing the video. The question is if your server-side script (whether its php or asp.net or anything else) can output something that the client will interpret as "autoplay this video".

Comment: Oh man, you and everyone in earshot are gonna *love* the first five seconds of this song!

Comment: Note that if you autoplay the video, in an embedded YouTube player, the official view count is not augmented. The user has to start the video for it to count as a view.

Comment: You have to query the YouTube api to get the duration of the video - I don't think there's any other way, other than some hacky screenscrape of the watch page, or playlist it's on, or some other YouTube page featuring that video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [autoplay parameter](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html#autoplay). Just append it to the urls in the src attribute and the movie parameter.

Comment: You have a typo in the URL, the correct one is http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html#autoplay

Comment: But how to get the TOTAL PLAY TIME of the particular video. Is there any way... That much important...